# Function in class have not the same number of arguments that function out of class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, tkinter

I try to improve my beginning's skills in Python (2.7) (and my english...).

I've wrote a code to compare 2 files in a graph. That's work !
So I try to make an interface for changing more easily the title, range, axis's name...

I use Tk library and ttk. I start by making a class for the frame and define function for repetitive task. "It's a good idea", I think. Ha ha ha. 
Some issue I've encounter :

- variable in function aren't global so I can't use the result of the function and I didn't find how to resolve that
- when a function is built into the class, an argument is always more, and the function run well out of the class...

I explain :

```
Class App(Object):
    functionInClass(arg1, arg2):
        pass
```

and

```
functionOutClass(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

When I call functionOutClass it's ok, but when I call App.functionInClass with the same arguments I always have an error message (function need 2 arguments, 3 is given). I didn't find how to resolve that.

I begin in Python, it's hard but it's a lot of fun !

Finally, my code run without class and without function for repetitive tasks, **but it's very very ugly !**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from os import getcwd, path
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog as filedialog
import shutil
import ttk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
wd = getcwd() # working directory

class Application(ttk.Frame):  # Not use
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = ttk.Button(self, text='Quitter', command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(column=2, row=3)


def champ(nom, defaut, col, ran, lab, collab, ranlab, largeur=7):
    nom = StringVar()  # Don't run
    nom = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=largeur, textvariable=nom)
    nom.insert(0, defaut)
    if nom.bind('<FocusIn>'):
        nom.delete(0, "end")
    nom.grid(column=col, row=ran, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=lab).grid(column=collab, row=ranlab, sticky=E)

def champdouble(nom1, defaut1, nom2, defaut2, col, ran, lab, lab2, collab, ranlab, largeur=7):  # Don't run
    nom1 = StringVar()
    nom1 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=largeur, textvariable=nom1)
    nom1.insert(0, defaut1)
    nom1.grid(column=col, row=ran, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=lab).grid(column=collab, row=ranlab, sticky=E)
    nom2 = StringVar()
    nom2 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=largeur, textvariable=nom2)
    nom2.insert(0, defaut2)
    nom2.grid(column=col+2, row=ran, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=lab2).grid(column=collab+2, row=ranlab, sticky=E)

def on_entry_click(event):
    """function that gets called whenever entry is clicked"""
    global dirname
    if file1.get() == 'Choisissez un fichier...':
        file1.delete(0, "end") # delete all the text in the entry
        dirinit = r'C:/'
        dirname = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=mainframe, initialdir=dirinit, title='Sélectionnez le fichier')
        file1.insert(0, dirname) #Insert blank for user input

def on_entry_click1(event):
    """function that gets called whenever entry is clicked"""
    global dirname2
    if file2.get() == 'Choisissez un fichier...':
       file2.delete(0, "end") # delete all the text in the entry
       dirinit = r'C:/'
       dirname2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=mainframe, initialdir=dirinit, title='Sélectionnez le fichier')
       file2.insert(0, dirname2) #Insert blank for user input

def callback():
    def traitement(fichier, deb, fin):
        df = pd.read_csv(fichier, sep = '\t', engine = 'python', header = deb, skipfooter = fin)  # Lecture des fichiers
        df = df.rename(columns={'$Relations :NumZoneE': 'NumZoneE'})  # Renommage des entêtes de colonnes
        df = df[(df.NumZoneE != df.NumZoneA)]  # supression des intrazonaux
        df = df[(df.NumZoneE <= 1289)]  # supression des zones superieures a 1289
        df = df[(df.NumZoneA <= 1289)]
        df['OD_possible']=np.where(df['JRTA'] < 999999, 'oui', 'non')  # creation d'une colonne OD_possible
        df = pd.merge(df, dvol, on = ['NumZoneE', 'NumZoneA'])  # jointure des tables avec dvol
        dfg = df.groupby('OD_possible')  # groupage selon oui ou non
        return dfg

    titrel = titre.get()
    file1_debl = int(file1_deb.get())
    file1_finl = int(file1_fin.get())
    file2_debl = int(file2_deb.get())
    file2_finl = int(file2_fin.get())
    cettecolonnel = cettecolonne.get()
    range1l = int(range1.get())
    range2l = int(range2.get())
    binsl = int(bins.get())
    legend1l = legend1.get()
    legend2l = legend2.get()
    axeXl = axeX.get()
    axeYl = axeY.get()
    sortiel = sortie.get()

    # Chemin d'acces vers les fichiers à traiter
    dvol = r'\\C:\1704_Test_maj_horaire_RERD_Sc2012\090721_DVOL_km.txt'

    # Traitement de dvol
    dvol = pd.read_csv(dvol, sep = '\t')  # Lecture
    dvol = dvol.rename(columns = {'ZONEO': 'NumZoneE', 'ZONED': 'NumZoneA'})  # Renommage entete
    dvol = dvol[(dvol.DVOL != 0)]  # Suppression intrazonaux

    fig = plt.figure()
    gss_oui = traitement(dirname, file1_debl, file1_finl).get_group('oui')
    gss_non = traitement(dirname, file1_debl, file1_finl).get_group('non')
    gac_oui = traitement(dirname2, file2_debl, file2_finl).get_group('oui')
    gac_non = traitement(dirname2, file2_debl, file2_finl).get_group('non')

    plt.hist([gss_oui[cettecolonnel], gac_oui[cettecolonnel]], range = (range1l, range2l), bins = binsl, label = [legend1l, legend2l])
    plt.legend(loc = 'best')
    plt.title(titrel)
    plt.xlabel(axeXl, labelpad = 5)
    plt.ylabel(axeYl)
    plt.savefig(path.join(wd, sortiel))
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app = Application()
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("BW.TEntry", foreground="grey", background="white")
    style.configure("BW1.TEntry", foreground="black", background="white")
    #app.master.title('Comparaison de fichiers')

    mainframe = ttk.Frame(padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # construction du champ file1
    file1 = StringVar()
    file1_deb = StringVar()
    file1_fin = StringVar()
    file1 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, style="BW.TEntry")
    file1.insert(0, 'Choisissez un fichier...')
    file1.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
    file1.bind('<FocusIn>', on_entry_click)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Fichier n° 1 : ").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
    file1_deb = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=file1_deb)
    file1_deb.insert(0, "26")
    file1_deb.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="ligne de début").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=E)
    file1_fin = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=file1_fin)
    file1_fin.insert(0, "1307")
    file1_fin.grid(column=6, row=1, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="lignes de fin à supprimer").grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=E)

    # construction du champ file2
    file2 = StringVar()
    file2_deb = StringVar()
    file2_fin = StringVar()
    file2 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, style="BW.TEntry")
    file2.insert(0, 'Choisissez un fichier...')
    file2.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=W)
    file2.bind('<FocusIn>', on_entry_click1)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Fichier n° 2 : ").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
    file2_deb = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=file2_deb)
    file2_deb.insert(0, "26")
    file2_deb.grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="ligne de début").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=E)
    file2_fin = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=file2_fin)
    file2_fin.insert(0, "1307")
    file2_fin.grid(column=6, row=2, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="lignes de fin à supprimer").grid(column=5, row=2, sticky=E)

    #champ("cettecolonne", "JRTA", 2, 3, "Champ à comparer :", 1, 3, 20)
    cettecolonne = StringVar()
    cettecolonne = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=cettecolonne)
    cettecolonne.insert(0, "JRTA")
    cettecolonne.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Champ à comparer :").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=E)

    #champ("titre", "Titre du graphique", 2, 4, "Titre du graphique :", 1, 4, 20)
    titre = StringVar()
    titre = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=titre)
    titre.insert(0, "Titre du graphique")
    titre.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Titre du graphique").grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E)

    #champdouble("range1", 0, "range2", 100, 2, 5, "Xmin :", "Xmax :", 1, 5)
    range1 = StringVar()
    range1 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=range1)
    range1.insert(0, 0)
    range1.grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Xmin :").grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=E)
    range2 = StringVar()
    range2 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=range2)
    range2.insert(0, 100)
    range2.grid(column=4, row=5, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Xmax :").grid(column=3, row=5, sticky=E)

    #champ("bins", 20, 2, 6, "Nombre d'intervalle :", 1, 6, 5)
    bins = StringVar()
    bins = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=5, textvariable=bins)
    bins.insert(0, 20)
    bins.grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Nombre d'intervalle :").grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=E)

    #champdouble("legend1", "file1", "legend2", "file2", 2, 7, "Légende du fichier n°1 :", "Légende du fichier n°2 :", 1, 7, 20)
    legend1 = StringVar()
    legend1 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=legend1)
    legend1.insert(0, "fichier 1")
    legend1.grid(column=2, row=7, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Légende du fichier n°1 :").grid(column=1, row=7, sticky=E)
    legend2 = StringVar()
    legend2 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=legend2)
    legend2.insert(0, "fichier 2")
    legend2.grid(column=4, row=7, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Légende du fichier n°2 :").grid(column=3, row=7, sticky=E)

    #champ("axeX", "Axe des X", 2, 8, "Nom de l'axe des x :", 1, 8, 20)
    axeX = StringVar()
    axeX = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=axeX)
    axeX.insert(0, "Axe des X")
    axeX.grid(column=2, row=8, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Nom de l'axe des x :").grid(column=1, row=8, sticky=E)

    #champ("axeY", "Axe des Y", 2, 9, "Nom de l'axe des y :", 1, 9, 20)
    axeY = StringVar()
    axeY = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=axeY)
    axeY.insert(0, "Axe des Y")
    axeY.grid(column=2, row=9, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Nom de l'axe des y :").grid(column=1, row=9, sticky=E)

    #champ("sortie", "image.png", 2, 10, "Nom du .png sauvegardé :", 1, 10, 20)
    sortie = StringVar()
    sortie = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=sortie)
    sortie.insert(0, "image.png")
    sortie.grid(column=2, row=10, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Nom du .png sauvegardé :").grid(column=1, row=10, sticky=E)

    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="clic !", command=callback).grid(column=4, row=10, sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Quitter', command=quit).grid(column=5, row=10, sticky=W)

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot the `self` argument used to reference the instance. In C++ or Java, `this` is  keyword that automatically reference the instance. Python uses a different convention: the first argument of the *definition* of a method is a reference to the instance, and by convention, Python programmers use `self` as the instance reference name. The common usage is:

```
>>> class App(object):   # defines a class
    def functionInClass(self, arg1, arg2):  # declares a method with 2 parameters
        pass # add more insteresting stuff later...
        self._arg1 = arg1  # how to set a instance member for later reuse


>>> a = App() # creates an instance of App
>>> a.functionInClass("arg1", "arg2") # and call the method on the instance
```

Comment: Oh my... I used that in other code... It's a typo the "_" in self._arg1 ? Otherwise I don't understand it.  Thanks for your answer !